# Java MVC InvalidationListener

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller, observable, listener

I have a Model that contains different variables and a list of InvalidationListeners. When something changes, i call fireInvalidationEvent(), which is a method that calls invalidated(this) on each listener.

However, I am having trouble with this due to the fact that the invalidated function is too general, in case for example the pageNumber changes, the controller that listens to this model only needs to change the TableView but nothing else. Below you have my current code:

```
public class DataModel implements Observable {
    // different variables
    private int pageNumber;
    private List<InvalidationListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    // code to override Observable methods (add and remove listeners) and getters and setters for variable
    // setters call fireInvalidationEvent() when variable has changed

    private void fireInvalidationEvent(){
        for (InvalidationListener listener : listeners){
            listener.invalidated(this);
        }
    }
}

public class Controller implements InvalidationListener {
   // Specific code for controller
   @Override
   public void invalidated(Observable obs){
      // do something with values of model
      // do something else if only pageNumber has changed!
   }
}
```

This code works but does too much, it does the same for every change.
It should do something else if **only** pageNumber has changed, only is in fat because the change of some variables also sets the pageNumber back to default.

How can I do this?

Comment: [mcve] please .. don't understand why you are re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: Implement your model with [JavaFX properties](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/package-summary.html); then you can add different listeners to each property.